# Attempting to create a calender with a clock picker built into each day as an ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I understand that this sounds a bit far fetched but i want to build a monthly calendar that when the day is clicked it is routed to another page that then prompts the user to put in a start and end time which the program then calculates the total amounts of hours and assigns it to the original calendar. I have found a few j query plugins however when combined or any of their code is manipulated they both seem to break. If you have any suggestions anything is welcomed. I can upload what i have for code so far but its not really flushed out or good at all.

Comment: Please do include what you have.  It will help narrow your broad question.  On another note, mixing JQuery and Angular can lead to some bad behavior since there might be two different things trying to manipulate the same HTML.

Comment: can't help without more info about what `break` means and seeing the code you are trying to use